# Aligning images of different sizes

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a different size of image to be input as a thumbnail of a tableview, is there a way to make all the image align despite their different in size? since in my case, the location of the text will follow the image, so it won't be neat.
Here's the code that I use to input the image

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.textLabel.text = title;
cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
cell.imageView.image = thumb;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the frame of the `imageView` and `textLabel` objects as you want them to be.

Comment: I did try that method, even after I indicated the frame, it never move, all of the content still not align.

Comment: can you provide a picture of the problem?

Comment: I need to make the image all align together to the center, despite their different sizes, then I try specifying the frame X n Y, so that all will be align with some rough calculation, but it turn out all the image still in the same position, none of them respond to my frame function.

Answer (score 1):

Cell.imageView is a UIImageView, which is a subclass of UIView. Look at documentation of [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) - exactly "Configuring the Resizing Behavior". Maybe something of that helps.

But beware - resizing on the fly can reduce scrolling behaviour of the tableview. Maybe better way is to resize images to fit the size of the uiimageview **before** actually using them in tableview.